# How can I access the cell of the table in jquery

Tags: jquery

**How Can I access the cell of the rows of the table (JQuery)**

```
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
                {
                if(document.getElementById(myData[i]).value !=0)
                {
                var nameInput = document.getElementById(myData[i]).name;

                var Quan = document.getElementById(myData[i]).value;
                //Create a new row with an ID
                var newRow = $('<tr />').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumber);
                //Add some HTML to the row
                newRow.html('<td>' + nameInput + '</td><td>' + Quan + '</td>');

                //Append the new row to the body of the #myTable table
                $('#myTable tbody').append(newRow);

                //Iterate row number
                rowNumber++;
                }
                }
```

I'm creating the table dynamically and want to use the previous value of the cell to add in to the new one. Can you please guide how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about first storing the html codes in string then set it to the table.

```
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
                    {
                    if(document.getElementById(myData[i]).value !=0)
                    {
                    var nameInput = document.getElementById(myData[i]).name;

                    var Quan = document.getElementById(myData[i]).value;
                    //Create a new row with an ID
                    var newRow = $('<tr />').attr('id', 'row' + rowNumber);
                    //Add some HTML to the row 
var htmlCodes = "<tr id='row"+ rowNumber+"'><td>"+nameInput+"</td><td>"+ Quan +"</td></tr>"



                    //Iterate row number
                    rowNumber++;
                    }

                    $('#myTable').html(htmlCodes);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ID for the td too and just simply select it by

```
$('#_yourid_')
```

or

```
document.getElementById('_yourid_')
```

Or if the row has an id, then

```
$('#row'+rowNumber).find('td')
```

And you can select the first cell by:

```
$('#row'+rowNumber).find('td:first')
```

And the last by

```
$('#row'+rowNumber).find('td:last')
```

And perhaps try to use jQuery all the way down, that usually helps to make the code look cleaner...